# Gridview scrolling wierd effect

Tags: android, gridview, android-view, android-gridview, baseadapter

So i have this problem with the gridview scrolling. The the top of the list goes into an endless scroll.

Here are some pictures describing the issue:

[image]

[image]

I'm using a base adapter as a adapter for the gridview, here is the getView class:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v = convertView;
        GalleryHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

            v = li.inflate(R.layout.gridview_files_layout, null);
            holder = new GalleryHolder();

            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.transparentView = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.transparentView);
            holder.selectImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.selectImageView);
            holder.selectButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
            holder.nameText = (EllipsizingTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.sizeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sizeTextView);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (GalleryHolder) v.getTag();
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I think it has something to do related with this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16218

I have changed the gridview to fixed height and it seems that the issue doesn't appear anymore. Will make some more tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a known android bug. Setting my griview_item_layout imageview to fixed height/width, textview to fixed number of lines fixed the issue.